# What's the different between AddObject and Attach when transfer a enttity from one context to another

Tags: entity-framework, objectcontext

If I have use database first to build a context, and instantiate this context twice. I want to query a specific entity from the first context and add it to the second context, what's the different between using AddObject and Attach.
eg.

```
Student stu = context1.Students.First();
context1.Detach(stu);
context2.Attach(stu);
```

and

```
Student stu = context1.Students.First();
context1.Detach(stu);
context2.Students.AddObject(stu);
```

What's the difference between them?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx) method will attach the object or object graph in **Unchanged** state. That means if you don't do any modifications to the object after you attach it, EF will not issue any Update/Delete commands for that object when you call `SaveChanges()` method.

But when you use `AddObject` method EF will insert the object as a new entity in `SaveChanges()` method.

If the `context2` is connected to a different database and you want to copy the instance then you can use `AddObject`. Otherwise use the `Attach` method.

Comment: I cannot say for how much time I am trying to figure it out, the difference regarding Add and Attach. All is clear now!